# Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: wlan0 error: No such file or directory

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I was following this Raspberry Pi documentation (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md) about connecting to wireless connection. My SSID and password are correct.

Whenever I use the command:

```
ifconfig wlan0
```

It has an inet addr value.

I used the command:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

It displays all the available WiFi connections.

But when I try using the command:

```
sudo wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure
```

It says "Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: wlan0  error: No such file or directory"

Any of you have encountered this? I followed the documentation and all but it doesn't seem to tackle this problem.

Comment: What documentation? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to connect to my WiFi. This documentation: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md

Comment: Any detail should be edited into your question - not in Comments. This still doesn't explain "What are you trying to do" - you should list **what YOU did** in detail, also **WHY** - this is normally unnecessary.

Comment: OK, wpa_cli gives you an error message but the interface is working (scanning works) and it is associated to an access point (getting ip address). Where is the real problem? I had no need to use wpa_cli so far.

Comment: I have this problem on my Gentoo desktop with RTL8188CUS

Comment: Did you fix your problem? I have the same issue (`Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: wlan0 error: No such file or directory
`) with Raspbian Buster. I have unblocked WiFi with `sudo rfkill unblock wifi`.

Comment: 2 years without anyone posting a solution. Maybe its unsolveable? Though it would be weird if raspberry pi has gone 2 years without wireless and nobody noticed. So Im guessing its solveable.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and realized that `wlan0` wasn't up. Just activate the interface with `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` and then scan again with `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo killall wpa_supplicant
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -D wext -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -B
```